# How could I iterate through a list of list in kernel?

Tags: c, linux, struct, kernel

I have a list implemented into another list, but I don't know how to iterate through it. Could you, please, help me with this?

```
LIST_HEAD(first_list);
LIST_HEAD(second_list);

struct my_first_list {

  struct list_head next;

  int variable_a;

}


struct my_second_list {

  struct list_head next;

  int variable_b;

  struct my_first_list *my_list;

}
```

I populated my_first_list like this:

```
struct my_second_list *sec_list_element;

list_for_each(p, &second_list) {

  sec_list_element = list_entry(p, struct my_second_list, next);

  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    sec_list->my_list->variable_a = 1;

    list_add(&sec_list_element->my_list->next, &first_list);

  }

}
```

Now, I don't know how to take my elements back..
I tried to do something like:

```
my_first_list *first_list_element;
my_second_list *sec_list_element;
list_for_each(p, &second_list) {

  sec_list_element = list_entry(p, struct my_second_list, next);

  list_for_each(q, &first_list) {

    first_list_element = list_entry ... // and here i'm not sure what to do

  }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: How is it related to kernel?

Comment: This is a kernel module. I want to write something in kernel (in linux)

Comment: Please, in the population code make identificators to be consistent. `second_list` seems to be a `sec_list`, but what is `my_first_list` in the `list_add()` call? Field `.my_list` is a pointer to something which should be allocated, but I see no call to allocation function before you set `sec_list->my_list->variable_a = 1;`. Also note, that you cannot add the **same element** into the list more than once, as you do in `list_add(&sec_list->my_list->children, &my_first_list);`.

Comment: This is not exactly the code I used. In my source code I allocated and initialized everything.
Also, in my source code i don't use a for to do this, I call the function that adds elements to my list with different parameters. 
So this is a example to simply the explanations to get to the problem that i struggle.
Thank you!

Comment: You expect us to understand what do you want from the structures definitions **without any comment** and with very **imprecise code**. But things are not so clear as you think. In the Linux kernel every double linked list consists from the **head** (of plain type `struct list_head`) and from the field of type `struct list_head` **embedded** into each element. Assuming `.children` field is that embedded field (note, in that case the field's name is quite *misleading*), what are the **heads** for your lists? How can we iterate over your lists without knowing their heads?